# Find all records associated with a user in same group as current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My models: User, Group, GroupsUser, and Availability.

I want to find all Availabilities created by users who are associated to a group, or several groups.

```
class Availability < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :groups, through: :group_users

  has_many :availabilities
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :users, through: :group_users
end

class GroupUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is what I've tried to find all Availabilities created by a user in the same group as the first user. How can I make this query?

```
user = User.first

Availability.joins(:user).where('user.groups.pluck[:id] IN (?)', user.groups.pluck[:id])
```

Would also be great to put a scope on the Group, but it throws an error each time I do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to do so:

1) Through the join

```
Availability.joins(user: :groups).distinct
```

2) Through the sub queries

```
Availability.where(user_id: User.joins(:groups).distinct.pluck(:id))
```

If you need to filter Availability with a specific group you can add `.where(groups: { name: 'Group name' })` condition

Comment: Unless I misunderstand I think the OP is looking for `Availability.where(user_id: GroupUser.select(:user_id).where(group_id: user.groups.select(:id)))` because she wants all the `Availability`s where `availabilities.user_id` is in the same group(s) as the current user. I could be wrong though

Answer (score 0):

Does this get what you're looking for?

```
class Availability < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :groups, through: :user

  scope :for_user_in_groups, lambda { |user|
    next all unless user.present?

    joins(user: :groups).where(groups: { id: user.groups.select(:id) }).distinct
  }
end
```

This produces:

```
[32] pry(main)> Availability.for_user_in_groups(User.find(2))
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Availability Load (0.8ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "availabilities".* FROM "availabilities" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "availabilities"."user_id" INNER JOIN "group_users" ON "group_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "group_users"."group_id" WHERE "groups"."id" IN (SELECT "groups"."id" FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "group_users" ON "groups"."id" = "group_users"."group_id" WHERE "group_users"."user_id" = $1)  [["user_id", 2]]
  => [#<Availability:0x00007fd3830bae38 id: 6, user_id: 3>,
    #<Availability:0x00007fd3830bacf8 id: 5, user_id: 2>,
    #<Availability:0x00007fd3830babb8 id: 3, user_id: 3>,
    #<Availability:0x00007fd3830baa78 id: 2, user_id: 2>]
```